# How to completely stop the rails action from responding any kind of HTTP status?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

***RAILS 3.2.13. JRUBY 1.7.15. RUBY 1.9.3 as interpreter***

Is there a way to kill a Rails action from responding at all? I want to do this to avoid any kind of response being sent back to anonymous hacker. There is a constraint check before index and if the constraint check fails, index method ideally should stop from responding. This is a small part on REST API in an effort to kill the action from sending any http status back.

Any constructive suggestion are welcomed.

i.e.

```
def index
  # kill method, do not send any response at all. not even 500 error
end
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Could you please explain me why you down voted it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a REST API should probably send a valid HTTP response, you can suppress any output by closing the underlying output stream. This is exposed via Rack's [hijacking](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/file/SPEC#Hijacking) API (assuming your server supports it):

```
def index
  if env['rack.hijack?']
    env['rack.hijack'].call
    io = env['rack.hijack_io']
    io.close
  end
end
```

This results in an empty reply, i.e. the server just closes the connection without sending any data:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:3000/
* Connected to localhost port 3000
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Comment: Is there a source code for rack.hijack ? I can't seem to find it in rack? Thanks.

Comment: @TheMouseMan it's implemented by the server. Here's how Puma implements `call`: https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/lib/puma/client.rb#L59